# Create custom registration form for Wordpress Multisite

Tags: plugins, themes, user-registration

I have Multisite Wordpress website and i've seen the default the registration from  but it did not meet all my requirements because i want to add more additional fields like Password field.

Comment: As it stands, your question is too broad and doesn't really show any initial effort on your part. There are many [similar questions already on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=create+registration+form). Start with those. If you need something beyond what you find and can do on your own, then post *that* as a new question with what you have put together.